# Google Fusion Tables upload

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Trying to follow instructions from google and upload a csv for a new fusion table. The page throws a very helpful error 'Import failed. Please retry.', and the dev console shows the server actually returned an http 405 error 'HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL'

page:
https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?dsrcid=implicit

Is there another way to upload csv files?

Comment: all crickets in their forum as well.. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-fusion-tables/xUU4rCfVdwc;context-place=forum/google-fusion-tables

Answer (score 1):

Your link suggests that you're trying to upload a 228mb file. I think I had some issued with large CSVs too. You *could* cut it up into smaller files until the error goes away, but IIRC the maximum file size is something like 5mb.

My preferred work-around is importing via Google Sheets. Upload your CSV to Drive, re-save it from Sheets, then import the Sheet into Fusion Tables.

Comment: Tried google sheets, it cannot handle the upload. Do not see the point of fusion tables for small amounts of data. Moving on to another solution. Thanks.